# Sql query showing to many values in one column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

**Column t.name(genre) is showing to many same values** I tried to make it work but i didn't succed..

Here is my SQL

```
select o.id, b.title, a.firstName, a.lastName, 
        b.noOfPages, b.price, group_concat(t.name) as 'genre'
from author a,book_author ba, book_type bt,orders o,type t, book b, order_list ol
where ol.book_fk = b.id 
and bt.book_fk = b.id 
and bt.type_fk = t.id 
and ba.author_fk = a.id 
and ba.book_fk = b.id 
and ol.orders_fk = '74' 
GROUP BY ol.id
```

Picture [image]

Picture is there to show how many values in column genre query returns

Comment: Hint:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us sample data and the expected output.  Note that your use of `GROUP BY` does not make much sense, because you are selecting non aggregate columns, and the `title` may not even be a primary key in its own table.

Comment: Hi. What is your question? When you edit your post to ask it, make sure you tell us what your query is supposed to return, and why what you are getting is wrong/problematic. [mcve] please. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text.

Comment: I edited it (Column t.name is showing to many same values I tried to make it work but i didn't succed..)

Comment: Image is there to show how much column genre is returning values

Comment: Hi. You don't seem to have paid attention to the comments Eg the link re text vs images: images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted, always include relevant text as text. Eg read your post: there is no question. And you are not explaining yourself clearly. Eg there's no MCVE. Etc. PS Google 'stackexchange notifications' to learn how to send comments to someone. If you don't use @ when there is more than one possibility then noone is notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are concerned with repeated values of "Crime" in your genre column.
Try using distinct inside group_concat.

```
select o.id, b.title, a.firstName, a.lastName,b.noOfPages, b.price,
group_concat(distinct t.name) as 'genre' from author a,book_author ba,
book_type bt,orders o,type t, book b, order_list ol where ol.book_fk = b.id
and bt.book_fk = b.id  and bt.type_fk = t.id and ba.author_fk = a.id
and ba.book_fk = b.id  and ol.orders_fk = '74' GROUP BY ol.id;
```